# "Junto a" vs "junto de"

Tags: significado, gramática

"**Junto a**" e "**junto de**" significam a mesma coisa ou são diferentes?

No google-translate os dois signifacam "**next to**"! Está certo?

Comment: E se usa o `junto com` também.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas as locuções podem ter um significado locativo (significando qualquer coisa como "em local adjacente a"):

> - Toda esta gente estaciona os seus automóveis **junto do** seu local de trabalho, num espaço que já é exíguo.
> - A Avenida Lusíada, que vai passar por cima da Segunda Circular, **junto ao** Estádio da Luz, abre ao trânsito amanhã à meia noite, quatro dias antes da abertura do vizinho Centro Comercial Colombo.

No entanto, em textos escritos, *junto de* é frequentemente usado em certas expressões, sem significado locativo óbvio, em lugar de *em*, *de*, *a*, *com* ou outras preposições:

> - A Associação Nacional de Freguesias, Anafre, vai solicitar ao Provedor de Justiça que interponha um recurso **junto do** [=ao] Tribunal Constitucional, para que seja declarada a inconstitucionalidade da generalidade da legislação corrente no que se refere às freguesias.
> - O Público tentou obter explicações sobre o processo **junto do** IAPMEI [=tentou obter do IAPMEI explicações...] (Instituto de Apoio às Pequenas e Médias Empresas Industriais), mas tal não se tornou possível em tempo útil.
> - A RTP garantiu já **junto do** [=obteve garantias do] gabinete do primeiro-ministro a realização do primeiro debate televisivo António Guterres / Marcelo Rebelo de Sousa -- onde fez chegar a sua pretensão, logo no dia 1 de Abril, a seguir portanto ao Congresso do PSD.
> - Estou também à espera de que haja um diálogo semelhante ao que houve com o eng. Mira Amaral, tanto com os industriais como com as estruturas associativas, visto que o anterior ministro da Indústria foi sempre visto por nós como o nosso representante **junto do** [=no] Governo.
> - O objectivo será resguardar o primeiro-ministro e secretário-geral do partido, e, simultaneamente, alargar o espaço político de alguns governantes com peso específico próprio no PS e **junto do** [=no] eleitorado.
> - Elvis tentou a sua sorte **junto do** [=com o] público da *country* indo cantar ao Grand Ole Opry, em Nashville, mas a sua aparição foi um desastre e o *manager* da Opry, Jim Denny, aconselhou-o a voltar para os camiões.

Os exemplos do [CETEMPúblico](http://www.linguateca.pt/cetempublico/) para *junto de* são, na maioria, deste tipo. É possível que no Brasil ocorra um fenómeno semelhante com *junto a* (veja-se [este artigo](https://exame.abril.com.br/carreira/quando-e-certo-usar-a-expressao-junto-a/) a criticar um uso semelhante de *junto a*).